# PowerBi new column with switch statement and dates

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, reporting

I am trying to update background color of a column in PowerBi report. For that I am trying to create a column in power BI report and adding a switch statement to display background as
Red if dates greater than 2 weeks
Green if dates less than 2 weeks etc.,

The switch statement is working fine for strings but not with dates. Any suggestion or pointer would help to make dates switch work.

**Working Switch** for string conditions by creating a new column

```
columnNameColorNumber = SWITCH(MyData[name],"abc",1,"def",2,3)
```

New column shows numbers as expected

**Failing Switch** when trying to create a column in power bi with date conditions

```
columnNameColorNumber = SWITCH(MyData[reqDate],"(MyData[reqDate]>(Today()-14))",1,2)
```

New column shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
columnNameColorNumber = SWITCH(TRUE(),MyData[reqDate]>Today()-14,1,2)
```

to add more switch checks it would look like this:

```
columnNameColorNumber = SWITCH(TRUE(),
   MyData[reqDate]>Today()-14,1,
   MyData[reqDate]>Today()-30,2,3)
```